# replace the exact word without replacing the not exact word with str_replace

Tags: php

i have this problem replacing a word but it replace other

```
$dbword = 'test text lorem ipsum ext';
$var1 = str_replace($dbword, 'ext', $var);
$var1 = str_replace($$dbword, 'text', $var1);
```

i want to replace the text without arranging the line, because the ext and text words are from the database and sorting the query is not the best way for me.

how can I replace the words without changing the look a like word? please help thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use str_replace(), use [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) because that allows you to check word boundaries

Comment: how can I do that with preg_replace() sir? :( I don't have any idea how to use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use preg_replace like :

```
$dbword = 'test text lorem ipsum ext';
$rplc = 'replaced';
$pattern = '/\bext\b/u';
$ret = preg_replace($pattern,$rplc,$dbword);//test text lorem ipsum replaced
$pattern2 = '/\btext\b/u';
$ret2 = preg_replace($pattern2,$rplc,$dbword);//test replaced lorem ipsum ext
```